Smoke noise creates weird pause?
So my smoke sim works fine until I add noise, then it creates this weird pause before it dissipates.
Here's the render: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/uecM8D57xzQ
and my sim settings -

any advice would be greatly appreciated.
thanks Blender Gang

Did you try setting the cache folder to something else than the default one ? It sometimes solves re-baking fluids issue.

Thanks for the suggestion - I already made a custom cache folder... but I just realised I put that folder inside of the default cache folder (not sure if that's problematic but seems like it could be an issue), so I've moved it out and will try adding noise again :)

The issue persists after changing the location of the cache folder :(

Ticking the "Slow" check box under Time in the Dissolve menu of the Smoke domain seems to have fixed the issue. No idea why.

It really is a strange behavior. Consider sharing your file with https://blend-exchange.com/
